# Prevent crash in string manipulation crashing whole application

Tags: c

I created a program which at regular intervals downloads a text file from a website, which is in csv format, and parses it, extracting relevant data, which then is displayed.

I have noticed that occasionally, every couple of months or so, it crashes. The crash is rare, considering the cycle of data downloading and parsing can happen every 5 minutes or even less. I am pretty sure it crashes inside the function that parses the string and extracts the data. When it crashes it happens during a congested internet connection, i.e. heavy downloads and/or a slow connection. Occasionally the remote site may be handing corrupt or incomplete data.

I used a test application which saves the data to be processed before processing it and it indeed shows it was not complete when a crash happens.

I have adapted the function to accommodate for a number of cases of invalid or incomplete data, as well as checking all return values. I also check return values of the various functions used to connect to the remote site and download the data. And will not go further when a return value indicates no success.

The core of the function uses strsep() to walk through the data and extract information out of it:

```
/ *
  * delimiters typically contains: <;>, <">, < >
  * strsep() is used to split part of the string using delimiter
  * and copy into token which then is copied into the array
  * normally the function stops way before ARRAYSIZE which is just a safeguard
  * it would normally stop when the end of file is reached, i.e. \0
  */
for(n=0;n<ARRAYSIZE;n++)
{
  token=strsep(&copy_of_downloaded_data, delimiters);
  if (token==NULL)
    break;

  data->array[n].example=strndup(token, strlen(token));

  if (data->array[n].example!=NULL)
  {
    token=strsep(&copy_of_downloaded_data, delimiters);
    if (token==NULL)
      break;

  (..)

  copy_of_downloaded_data=strchr(copy_of_downloaded_data,'\n'); /* find newline */
  if (copy_of_downloaded_data==NULL)
    break; 

  copy_of_downloaded_data=copy_of_downloaded_data+1;
  if (copy_of_downloaded_data=='\0') /* find end of text */
    break;
}
```

Since I suspect I can not account for all ways in which data can be corrupted I would like to know if there is a way to program this so the function when run does not crash the whole application in case of corrupted data.

If that is not possible what could I do to make it more robust.

Edit: One possible instance of a crash is when the data ends abruptly, where the middle of a field is cut of, i.e.

> "test","example","this data is brok

At least I noticed it by looking through the saved data, however I found it not being consistent. Will have to stress test it as was suggested below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best thing to do would be to figure out what input causes the function to crash, and fix the function so that it does not crash.  Since the function is doing string processing, this should be possible to do by feeding it lots of dummy/test data (or feeding it the "right" test data if it's a particular input that causes the crash).  You basically want to torture-test the function until you find out how to make it crash on demand; at that point you can start investigating exactly where and why it crashes, and once you understand that, the necessary changes to fix the crash will probably become obvious to you.

Running the program under valgrind might also point you to the bug.

If for some reason you can't fix the bug, the other option is to spawn a child process and run the buggy code inside the child process.  That way if it crashes, only the child process is lost and not the parent.  (You can spawn the child process under most OS's by calling fork(); you'll need to come up with some way for the child process to communicate its results back to the parent process, of course).  (Note that doing it this way is a kludge and will likely not be very efficient, and could also introduce a security hole into your application if someone malicious who has the ability to send your program input can figure out how to manipulate the bug in order to take control of the child process -- so I don't recommend this approach!)

Comment: If someone could take control of the child process, they could also take control of the process now

Comment: Very good suggestions, thanks. I have been thinking about feeding it test data. I did use valgrind for a while in earlier stages of development and I fixed all the fixable things it found to be wrong. The bug can only trigger every couple of months, though sometimes a few times in one day, then nothing for weeks, which makes it less practical to run in debuggers and similar tools.

Comment: I've found valgrind to be very helpful for tracking down the cause of "once in a blue moon" crashes.  Often they are due to subtle memory corruption bugs that have no visible effects 99.9% of the time; valgrind can make the hidden corruption more visible.

Comment: Right, will try using valgrind again.

Answer (score 1):

What does the coredump point to?

strsep - does not have memory synchronization mechanisms, so protect it as a critical section ( lock it when you do strsep ) ?

see if strsep can handle a big chunk ( ARRAYSIZE is not gonna help you here ).

stack size of the thread/program that receives copy_of_downloaded_data ( i know you are only referencing it so look at the function that receives it. )

Comment: When I ran the application through gdb it would crash in the function I mentioned above. The copy_of_downloaded_data is an actual separate copy of the original downloaded data, because strsep() actually changes the data. What do you mean by locking it?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that one should try to write code that keeps track of string lengths deliberately and doesn't care whether strings are zero-terminated or not.  Even though null pointers have been termed the "billion dollar mistake"(*) I think zero-terminated strings are far worse.  While there may be some situations where code using zero-terminated strings might be "simpler" than code that tracks string lengths, extra effort required to make sure that nothing can cause string-handling code to exceed buffer boundaries exceeds that required when working with known-length strings.

If, for example, one wants to store the concatenation of strings of length `length1` and `length2` into a buffer if length `BUFF_SIZE`, one can test easily whether `length1+length2 <= BUFF_SIZE` if one isn't expecting strings to be null-terminated, or `length1+length2 < BUFF_SIZE` if one expects a gratuitous null byte to follow every string.  When using zero-terminated strings, one would have to determine the length of the two strings before concatenation, and having done so one could just as well use `memcpy()` rather than `strcpy()` or the useless `strcat()`.

(*) There are many situations where it's much better to have a recognizably-invalid pointer than to require that pointers which can't point to anything meaningful must instead point to something meaningless.  Many null-pointer related problems actually stem from a failure of implementations to trap arithmetic with null pointers; it's not fair to blame null pointers for problems that could have been, but weren't avoided.

Comment: Null terminated and zero terminated are the same thing?

Comment: @ColeJohnson: I prefer the term "zero-terminated" since the terminator is a byte whose value is zero.  In ASCII, code zero is called a "null byte" since it will not cause a teletype to do anything, and its paper-tape representation is blank, and thus the zero byte at the end of a string is often called the "null byte", but what's important to string methods is not that the character code represents a "null character", but rather that it's numeric value is zero.  Even if a C implementation used a character set where a null character was code 42, strcpy would still copy to the first zero byte.

Comment: I think it may make the function overly complex to take string size into account as opposed null termination. However you may have a point of course, since a potential bug may very well be in the '/0' test. As an aside, wouldn't you be better of using strncpy() and strncat()? As far as know strcpy() and strcat() and the likes are frowned upon nowadays because of buffer overflow problems.

Comment: @aseq: strncpy doesn't work the way many people think it does (it doesn't ensure the result is zero-terminated, but zero-fills the space after the string), and strncat is basically useless (it limits the length of the string to be appended, rather than the result; if one doesn't know the length of the string to be appended to, one can't know how much one can afford to append to it, and if one does know there's no reason to use a method that searches for the end of the string to be appended to.